# enable_if allowing base class only

Tags: inheritance, c++11, operator-overloading, crtp, enable-if

I'm currently implementing some CRTP with a base class `template<class CRTP> Base` and derived classes `Derived1 : public Base<Derived1>`, `Derived2 : public Base<Derived2>`...

The mathematical operators are defined in `Base` and are of the type `CRTP Base<CRTP>::operator+(const CRTP& rhs)` that means that we can add a `Derived1` to a `Derived1` but not a `Derived2` to a `Derived1`.

Furthermore, I have defined the operator `Base<CRTP>& Base<CRTP>::operator()()` which means that `Derived1()` will return `Base<Derived1>&`.

I wonder if there is a solution to do the following :

```
Derived1 = Derived1 + Derived1 : OK
Derived2 = Derived2 + Derived2 : OK
Derived1 = Derived1 + Derived2 : NOT OK
Derived1 = Derived1() + Derived2() : OK
```

According to the last two lines :

- I prevent the user to make a mistake
- But if he really wants to do this operation he can "cast" the derived types to the base type and it will work

The only thing I need to do this is to define an operator like that :

```
template<class CRTP0, class = typename std::enable_if</* SOMETHING */>::type> 
Base<CRTP> Base<CRTP>::operator+(const Base<CRTP0>& rhs)
```

In the enable_if I would like something that is :

- `true` : if rhs is of the `Base` type
- `false` : if rhs is a `Derived` type

Does a such thing exist ? Do you have an other solution in mind ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The */* SOMETHING */* can be easily archived using

1. `std::is_same` for the 'false' part of Derived and
2. A helper class for the 'true' part of Base

The helper class is to determine whether a class is exactly a `Base<?>`:

```
template <typename> struct IsBase : std::false_type {};
...
template <typename X> struct IsBase<Base<X>> : std::true_type {};
```

and then we could fill in that */* SOMETHING */* with:

```
std::is_same<Other, Self>::value || IsBase<Other>::value
```

Note that this allows `Derived1 + Derived2()`.

---

Example: http://ideone.com/OGt0Q

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename> struct IsBase : std::false_type {};

template <typename Self>
struct Base {
    Base& operator()() {
        return *this;
    };

    template <typename Other,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Other, Self>::value
                                              || IsBase<Other>::value>::type>
    Self operator+(const Other& other) const {
        return static_cast<const Self&>(*this);
    }
};

template <typename X> struct IsBase<Base<X>> : std::true_type {};


struct D1 : Base<D1> {};
struct D2 : Base<D2> {};


int main() {
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
    d1 + d1; // ok
    d2 + d2; // ok
    d1() + d2(); // ok
    d1 + d2; // error
}
```